# profile detail using popups window android?

Tags: android, dialog, popup, chat

I've just created a chat app for android, I got a problem to create a place for user profile using popups,,,in top of popups is image,and bellow is detail..(detail consist of contact,chat,timeline etc which is limited by an appearing tab) as the picture bellow,,,[center picture...]

http://developer.android.com/design/media/dialogs_popups_example.png

Where can I get the link to solve this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this documentation is for you : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

It's explain custom dialog, listDialog, ... If you would replicate Contact Dialog, you can try Custom dialog with Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. There is one more way to do this without the dialog. I used this trick on one of my project...

Create following theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then set this as the theme for your activity in the manifest file as shown in the  following code:

```
<activity android:name=".YourDialogActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"></activity>
```

now you can put whatever you want to put on your `Activity` and it would look like the one in the screenshot..